# Xubuntu 14.04 Power button instantly powers off laptop instead of showing shutdown menu

Tags: xubuntu, power-management, shutdown

Laptop is Lenovo Thinkpad X120e.
[lshw -short output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7287837/)
[/proc/cpuinfo](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7287845/)

The setup is pretty much standard. Not customized in any way, since I just installed it. No packages related to drivers installed, except for mesa-vdpau-drivers and vdpau-va-driver for video acceleration. Using standard radeon driver for graphics.

This is a pretty serious problem because I go to high school, and there are some very annoying people that like to run by and press the power button on my laptop as I'm working. Normally this would bring up the shutdown menu, but here it instantly powers off the computer without even going through the normal shut down process. Quite disastrous if I'm working on something.

Any ideas as to what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

it seems systemd kicks in and handles the power button before the xfce power manager.

Try to set systemd to ignore the handling of lid close or power button press, edit the file /etc/systemd/logind.conf, remove the comment sign # from the beginning of the line and set the appropriate line to ignore:

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details

[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
Controllers=blkio cpu cpuacct cpuset devices freezer hugetlb memory perf_event
ResetControllers=
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
HandlePowerKey=ignore
HandleSuspendKey=ignore
HandleHibernateKey=ignore
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the whisker menu --> Settings --> Power Manager.

In the General tab, select 'Ask' option for the 'When power button is pressed'.

Comment: This is already enabled. The problem is that something more low-level than the XFCE power manager is intercepting the button press and instantly powering off the computer.